# Does the neutrino interact with the photon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, neutrinos, effective-field-theory

I know that the straight answer is no, but in my EFT course, where we're interested in nonrenormalizable operators of the Lagrangian, things aren't so straightforward.
The non-minimal QED Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{ren}+\mathcal{L}_{nonren}=\bar{e}(i\hat{D}-m)e-\frac{1}{4}F^2+\frac{1}{M}\bar{\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\nu F_{\mu\nu}$$
does the last term actually exist? If so, is it "naturally" small? If not, why, since it's allowed by symmetries?

To be clear, I'm asking if this interaction can appear in a theory like the one I wrote above (with abelian $F$, so only electron, photon, and neutrino) and if it can happen at the tree level.

Comment: Draw the loop diagram involving a W and a charged lepton, both coupling to γ.   Skobelev, V. V. "On the γ→ νν and ν→ γν reactions in strong magnetic fields." Zhurnal Ehksperimental'noj i Teoreticheskoj Fiziki 71, no. 4 (1976): 1263-1267.

Comment: [Ioannisian & Raffelt](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.55.7038).

Comment: To me this question seems to be "if I add a neutrino-photon interaction term to the Lagrangian by hand, can I get neutrinos and photons to interact?"

Comment: @JerrySchirmer yes, precisely that. "if I add a neutrino-photon interaction term **allowed by symmetry** *(which should, in principle, be the only mechanism to follow to write Lagrangians)* to the Lagrangian by hand, can I get neutrinos and photons to interact?"

Comment: If the loop diagrams are allowed by the symmetry, they are allowed in the SMEFT, of course....

Comment: @CosmasZachos what SM symmetry forbids it?

Comment: We settled that: no SM symmetry forbids it. Non-renormalizability suppresses it. Are you cool with the banal magnetic moment of the neutron?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that was the answer I was looking for: symmetry allows it, nonrenormalizability suppresses it. I don't understand what you mean by "cool with the banal magnetic moment"

Comment: I added an explanation in the answer. The 1/M is actually $m_\nu G_F$, a freakishly small scale, in contrast to the strong-interaction-scale 1/M of the neutron. M is what the underlying theory behind the SMEFT specifies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the neutrino may have a magnetic moment at the 1 loop level in vacuum, [cf here](http://www.phys.virginia.edu/Files/fetch.asp?EXT=Seminars:2508:SlideShow), e.g.
[image]

This is summarized by your unrenormalizable effective (fake tree)
dimension 5 operator, since the loop into which neutrinos can resolve involves charged leptons or gauge bosons.
Highly suppressed by the weak/EM coupling factor ([Fujikawa & Schrock, 1980](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.963)), $m_\nu G_F$.
In practical terms, the neutrino mass is so much smaller than the W mass that the question is "purely academic".$^\natural$    Your dimension 5 term you tacked on *needs* a dimension -1 coupling in front of it, for dimensional consistency. It is what's provided above.

There is a voluminous literature on the subject, but astrophysicists focus on interesting media beyond vacuum, affording enhancements, like intense magnetic fields, as cited in the comments above.

---

$^\natural$ You do notice your term *requires* a right-chiral neutrino. You might be alarmed that the Ws don't couple to it, but the Higgs, in similar diagrams, omitted here, does!

Comment: ... but it doesn't have a magnetic moment at tree level, even if in the Lagrangian there is a term that allows it? Namely: if the d.o.f. of my theories were only electrons, photons and neutrinos, would I have neutrino-photon interaction?

Comment: Of course not. The renormalizable Lagrangian does not allow it, but the SMEFT does.  Recall even the neutron has a magnetic moment. It is the weak diagrams, above, involving Ws, that pinch to the dimensions 5 operator of your SMEFT. You *must* put in the dimension -1 coupling constant there, of $O(G_F m_\nu)$.

Comment: Really nice answer. Do you think it makes sense to ask whether a gluon can interact with a photon?

Comment: @Árpád Szendrei  You are asking whether, since the gluon may resolve to quark-antiquark pairs which do couple to photons, you may have  effective gluon photon vertices? I can't see it, but this is a very different question... The η decays to two photons or two gluons, so there is a notional effective vertex...